# How to resolve usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 - chown root su cannot be used

Tags: linux, centos

usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 .
How can this be fixed I am very new to Linux.
Does not allow me to access Super User or Root - though I am the only user. Permission also  denied for- chown***

Obviously I have messed up bigtime. as last resort like to uninstall or format drive and start fresh.

Thank You For Your Help

Comment: Unless you have some other way to become root, you need a Linux Live CD/USB to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

(In general, it could be helpful to show exactly what commands you tried and what the output was, and which Linux distribution you are using. So, I am not quite sure what your problem is here, but I'll try to help anyway.)

Some Linux distributions don't have you set a root password on installation, but encourage that you use `sudo` to run commands as root. The program `/usr/bin/sudo` is indeed owned by root (uid 0), and *must* be owned by root in order to work. So don't try to change that.

To use `sudo`, you type `sudo *command*` in the shell. `sudo` will then ask for your user password, and after you typed it, will execute the command with root privileges. It looks like this, in this example with the command `id`:

```
$ sudo id
[sudo] password for jyrgenn:           *** password typed here ***
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Please see that `id` prints `uid=0` here; that shows `id` is executed with root privileges.

If this doesn't solve your problem, please tell us which Linux distribution you are using, what exactly your are trying to accomplish, what commands you ran, and what the exact output or error message was.